# Catalina crashing at shutdown: “watchdog timeout: no checkins from watchdogd”

Tags: macos, catalina, crash, shutdown

I have a MacBook Air 2017 with 8GB of RAM and 1.8 GHz Dual-Core Intel Core i5,

After updating to macOS Catalina, while I’m using my laptop it would freeze and the screen would turn black with a folder sign with a question mark in the middle flashing. This happens a lot and when I reboot my laptop this message pops up:

```
panic(cpu 2 caller 0xffffff7f87171ad5): userspace watchdog timeout: no successful checkins from com.apple.logd in 120 seconds
service returned not alive with context : unresponsive dispatch queue(s): com.apple.firehose.drain-mem 
service: com.apple.logd, total successful checkins since load (830 seconds ago): 72, last successful checkin: 120 seconds ago
service: com.apple.WindowServer, total successful checkins since load (800 seconds ago): 80, last successful checkin: 0 seconds ago

Backtrace (CPU 2), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff912644b720 : 0xffffff800611a65d 
0xffffff912644b770 : 0xffffff8006254a75 
0xffffff912644b7b0 : 0xffffff80062465fe 
0xffffff912644b800 : 0xffffff80060c0a40 
0xffffff912644b820 : 0xffffff8006119d27 
0xffffff912644b920 : 0xffffff800611a117 
0xffffff912644b970 : 0xffffff80068c1ad8 
0xffffff912644b9e0 : 0xffffff7f87171ad5 
0xffffff912644b9f0 : 0xffffff7f871717fa 
0xffffff912644ba10 : 0xffffff800685397e 
0xffffff912644ba60 : 0xffffff7f87170cfe 
0xffffff912644bb60 : 0xffffff800685cba3 
0xffffff912644bca0 : 0xffffff80062035e2 
0xffffff912644bdb0 : 0xffffff80061203c8 
0xffffff912644be10 : 0xffffff80060f6d15 
0xffffff912644be70 : 0xffffff800610db22 
0xffffff912644bf00 : 0xffffff800622c065 
0xffffff912644bfa0 : 0xffffff80060c1226 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.driver.watchdog(1.0)[B6A95892-6C75-3CF5-A6CC-6D83F30FA1D5]@0xffffff7f87170000->0xffffff7f87178fff

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: watchdogd

Mac OS version:
19H2

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 19.6.0: Mon Aug 31 22:12:52 PDT 2020; root:xnu-6153.141.2~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 05D51A3D-3A87-3FF0-98C3-9CF3827A3EDD
Kernel slide:     0x0000000005e00000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8006000000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8005f00000
System model name: MacBookAir7,2 (Mac-937CB26E2E02BB01)
System shutdown begun: NO
Panic diags file available: YES (0x0)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 838988891518
last loaded kext at 18297244763: org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetAdp 6.1.16 (addr 0xffffff7f89c9b000, size 28672)
loaded kexts:
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetAdp  6.1.16
com.avast.PacketForwarder   2.1
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetFlt  6.1.16
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxUSB 6.1.16
com.avast.FileShield    4.0.0
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxDrv 6.1.16
@fileutil   20.036.15
>AudioAUUC  1.70
>AGPM   111.4.4
>!APlatformEnabler  2.7.0d0
>X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
@filesystems.autofs 3.0
>!AHDAHardwareConfigDriver  283.15
>!AUpstreamUserClient   3.6.8
>!AHDA  283.15
>!AGraphicsDevicePolicy 5.2.6
@AGDCPluginDisplayMetrics   5.2.6
>!AHV   1
|IOUserEthernet 1.0.1
|IO!BSerialManager  7.0.6f7
>pmtelemetry    1
@Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X    7.0.0
>!A!IBDWGraphics    14.0.7
>AGDCBacklightControl   5.2.6
>!A!ISlowAdaptiveClocking   4.0.0
>!ABacklight    180.3
>ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    1.0.0
>!AMCCSControl  1.14
>!A!IBDWGraphicsFramebuffer 14.0.7
>!AFIVRDriver   4.1.0
>eficheck   1
>!AThunderboltIP    3.1.4
>!ACameraInterface  7.6.0
>!ALPC  3.1
>!ASMCLMU   212
|IO!BUSBDFU 7.0.6f7
|SCSITaskUserClient 422.120.3
>!U!SCoexistentDriver   489.120.1
>!UCardReader   489.120.1
>!ATopCaseHIDEventDriver    3430.1
>!AFileSystemDriver 3.0.1
>!AVirtIO   1.0
@filesystems.hfs.kext   522.100.5
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeDataless    1.0.0d1
@BootCache  40
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeZlib    1.0.0
@filesystems.apfs   1412.141.1
>!AAHCIPort 341.140.1
>AirPort.BrcmNIC    1400.1.1
@private.KextAudit  1.0
>!ASmartBatteryManager  161.0.0
>!ARTC  2.0
>!AACPIButtons  6.1
>!AHPET 1.8
>!ASMBIOS   2.1
>!AACPIEC   6.1
>!AAPIC 1.7
$!AImage4   1
@nke.applicationfirewall    303
$TMSafetyNet    8
@!ASystemPolicy 2.0.0
|EndpointSecurity   1
|IOUSBUserClient    900.4.2
@kext.triggers  1.0
>DspFuncLib 283.15
@kext.OSvKernDSPLib 529
>!AGraphicsControl  5.2.6
|IOAVB!F    850.1
@!AGPUWrangler  5.2.6
|IOSlowAdaptiveClocking!F   1.0.0
>!ABacklightExpert  1.1.0
|IONDRVSupport  576.1
>IOPlatformPluginLegacy 1.0.0
>!ASMBus!C  1.0.18d1
@!AGraphicsDeviceControl    5.2.6
|IOAccelerator!F2   438.7.3
>X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
>!AThunderboltEDMSink   4.2.3
>!AThunderboltDPOutAdapter  6.2.6
>IOPlatformPlugin!F 6.0.0d8
>!ASMBusPCI 1.0.14d1
>!AHDA!C    283.15
|IOGraphics!F   576.1
|IOHDA!F    283.15
@plugin.IOgPTPPlugin    840.3
|IOEthernetAVB!C    1.1.0
|Broadcom!BHost!CUSBTransport   7.0.6f7
|IO!BHost!CUSBTransport 7.0.6f7
|IO!BHost!CTransport    7.0.6f7
>usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice 1.2
>usb.!UHub  1.2
|IOUSBMass!SClass   4.0.4
>usb.cdc    5.0.0
>usb.networking 5.0.0
>usb.!UHostCompositeDevice  1.2
>!AHS!BDriver   3430.1
>IO!BHIDDriver  7.0.6f7
|IO!B!F 7.0.6f7
|IO!BPacketLogger   7.0.6f7
>!AMultitouchDriver 3440.1
>!AInputDeviceSupport   3440.8
>!AHIDKeyboard  209
>!AHSSPIHIDDriver   59
|IOAudio!F  300.2
@vecLib.kext    1.2.0
|IOSerial!F 11
|IOSurface  269.11
@filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext 1
>!AXsanScheme   3
|IOAHCIBlock!S  316.100.5
|IOAHCI!F   290.0.1
>!AThunderboltDPInAdapter   6.2.6
>!AThunderboltDPAdapter!F   6.2.6
>!AThunderboltPCIDownAdapter    2.5.4
>!AThunderboltNHI   5.8.6
|IOThunderbolt!F    7.6.1
|IO80211!F  1200.12.2b1
>mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
>corecapture    1.0.4
|IOSkywalk!F    1
>!AHSSPISupport 59
>!A!ILpssSpi!C  3.0.60
>!A!ILpssGspi   3.0.60
>!A!ILpssDmac   3.0.60
>!A!ILpssI2C    3.0.60
>usb.!UXHCIPCI  1.2
>usb.!UXHCI 1.2
>usb.!UHostPacketFilter 1.0
|IOUSB!F    900.4.2
>!AEFINVRAM 2.1
>!AEFIRuntime   2.1
|IOSMBus!F  1.1
|IOHID!F    2.0.0
$quarantine 4
$sandbox    300.0
@kext.!AMatch   1.0.0d1
>DiskImages 493.0.0
>!AFDEKeyStore  28.30
>!AEffaceable!S 1.0
>!ASSE  1.0
>!AKeyStore 2
>!UTDM  489.120.1
|IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice  422.120.3
>!ACredentialManager    1.0
>KernelRelayHost    1
>!ASEPManager   1.0.1
>IOSlaveProcessor   1
|IOUSBMass!SDriver  157.140.1
|IOSCSIArchitectureModel!F  422.120.3
|IO!S!F 2.1
|IOUSBHost!F    1.2
>!UHostMergeProperties  1.2
>usb.!UCommon   1.0
>!ABusPower!C   1.0
|CoreAnalytics!F    1
>!AMobileFileIntegrity  1.0.5
@kext.CoreTrust 1
|IOReport!F 47
|IOTimeSync!F   840.3
|IONetworking!F 3.4
>!AACPIPlatform 6.1
>!ASMC  3.1.9
>watchdog   1
|IOPCI!F    2.9
|IOACPI!F   1.4
@kec.pthread    1
@kec.Libm   1
@kec.corecrypto 1.0
```

I have gone to apple and they wiped my laptop and reinstalled macOS Catalina but the problem still persists. What do I do?

Comment: Have you updated *VirtualBox* and *Avast AntiVirus* to their latest versions?

Answer (score 0):

Updating to Monterey 12.3 would help get rid of kernel extensions - especially if you can back up your data and do another erase install.

---

I would start keeping a log of what’s connected to the computer. Since you’ve erased the machine, you’ve ruled out an install issue so this is either the changes you make to the software after its cleanly installed, the hardware itself or the hardware you attach.

Until you can make this happen on a clean OS with no data migrated or apps, it’s unlikely to be the OS itself or the hardware on the Mac.

I would focus first on accessories, then the software you install. Something is not exiting cleanly and the watchdog is letting you know that after waiting a reasonable amount of time for the shutdown process to complete, it pulled the plug and obeyed your shutdown command instead of hanging indefinitely for all the apps to exit cleanly.

There was a very insightful comment that belongs in an answer. Your system may have outdated versions of Avast and Virtual Box - consider uninstalling those or updating as appropriate.  This is exactly the thing we have cropped up on some older macs that had different anti virus, security and virtualization software installed. Backup and erase+install solved every single one.