# Windows Explorer stopped working after connecting external display (monitor) to My Apple Mac Book Air 2011

Tags: macbook-pro, display, windows, bootcamp

Earlier i was using Window 7 32 bit (bootcamp), and i have replaced my new SSD and load the windows 7 64 bit. After installing windows 7 64 bit, i was facing display driver issue due to incompatible drivers automatically loaded after running bootcamp, and intel HD graphic 4000 (version 10.18.10.5129)  installed. i restarted by laptop, and after restarting black screen was coming, so i copied the display driver (Intel HD graphic 4000 version 8.15.10.2778) from my 32 bit SSD and installed the driver. After installing display driver version 8.15.10.2778, i can boot in windows 7 bootcamp and also it is working fine but when i connect external display (monitor) via thunder bolt to VGA port then it is showing windows explorer stopped working and i have to restart the windows explorer then i can see the external display on my monitor. This error coming each time, i connect external display with my Mac.

Kindly help to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

[Malfunctioning cables, hubs and displays can cause good hardware to freeze](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/413901/5472), no matter which OS you choose. I would try running the Mac for several days without any accessories to validate it’s a cable or accessory causing the freeze.

Perhaps someone has got better troubleshooting expertise on windows than I and can answer thusly, but my steps above are often needed on troubleshooting macOS as well since they are so effective and easy to perform.